# Why does returning false in onkeydown method not work in Chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, onkeydown

I've got a bit of code that works perfectly fine in my desktop browser:

```javascript
document.getElementById('oneshot-timer-input').onkeydown = function(KeyboardEvent) {

    if (KeyboardEvent.key == "Backspace") {
        data.splice(-1,1);
    } else if (KeyboardEvent.key.length == 1 && !isNaN(Number(KeyboardEvent.key))) {
        if (data.length < 6) {
            if (data.length > 0 || KeyboardEvent.key != "0") {
                data.push(KeyboardEvent.key);
            }
        }
    }

    updateInputField();
    return false;
}
```

The value of the input field is set in another function by:

```javascript
document.getElementById('oneshot-timer-input').value = timeOutput;
```

It basically withholds the default action, and sets the value of the input field if some conditions are met (Only numbers and backspace are accepted). The base value is `00h 00m 00s`. When entering a number, it replaces a zero, starting from the right.

This works just fine in my desktop browser, but when I open the page on my phone, it adds the latest number to the end of the base value, so it reads `00h 00m 01s1` for example. It's never more than 1 extra number though, so another example could be `12h 34m 56s6`. Is there something Android related I'm missing here?

Comment: because that's not how JS events are meant to be used in modern JS. To listen for an event you use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), not the old "on..." syntax, and to prevent the browser from handling it "in the usual way" in addition to what your own code does, use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Not to be a partypooper, but calling `KeyboardEvent.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to do anything. At least, the behavior doesn't change whatsoever. It seems like I have missed the obvious though: onkeydown in Chrome on Android always returns keyCode 229, and "Unidentified" as key. I'll check if I can fix this, otherwise I'll change the question.

Comment: you call it on the event itself, not on the prototype object. `element.addEventListener("keydown", evt => { evt.preventDefault(); /* the rest of your code */ });`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JS, especially with all the shorthands, but isn't `element.addEventListener("keydown", evt =>` exactly the same as `element.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {`? I can see how my naming might be a bit confusing.

Comment: it's not really a shorthand, it's a different kind of function (called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). `(a,b,...) => ...` is indeed similar to `function(a,b,...) { ... }` but assigns a known meaning to `this` in the function's code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was missing the obvious: Android returns an unidentified key with keyCode 229 for every single key, at least when looking at the onkeydown method.

I added another EventListener on 'textInput', which handles the input perfectly. However, backspace is still an issue, since this doesn't trigger a keyevent at all. Sadly, this means that the text in the inputfield does get removed, but not as it's intended.

Implementation:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if (!isAndroid) {

    document.getElementById('oneshot-timer-input').onkeydown = function(KeyboardEvent) {

        var keyCode = KeyboardEvent.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 8 || (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)) {
            KeyboardEvent.preventDefault();
            handleKeyCode(KeyboardEvent.keyCode, KeyboardEvent.key);

        } else if (KeyboardEvent.key == "Escape") {
            setTimerState(TimerStateEnums.unlock, true);

        } else if (KeyboardEvent.key == "Enter") {
            document.getElementById("play-pause").checked = true;
            play_pause(document.getElementById("play-pause"));

        }
    }
} else {
    document.getElementById("oneshot-timer-input").addEventListener('textInput', function(TextEvent) {
        TextEvent.preventDefault();

        console.log(TextEvent);

        var char = TextEvent.data;
        var keyCode = char.charCodeAt(0);

        handleKeyCode(keyCode, char);

        return false;
    });
}
```